# What are 10 database transaction units in the Azure free trial?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cloud-services, azure-free-services

I am looking for a cloud service provider to host a SQL DB in and access through API calls. After looking through multiple providers I have seen that Azure has a 12-month free trial but only 250 GB S0 instance with 10 database transaction units.

Could anyone explain to be what they mean by 10 DB transaction units? Any help is greatly appreciated.

For reference our database would not be large in scale just holding candidate and judges applications which we only get maximum 600 candidates per year.

I tried looking transactional units online and saw it make be a single REST API call which seems absurd to me.

Comment: So contact Azure - they will explain their offer clearly.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tiers-dtu?view=azuresql#compare-service-tiers

Comment: This explains what DTUs are: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tiers-dtu?view=azuresql#database-transaction-units-dtus. In short, they are an abstract unit, it depends how complicated your queries are and how large datasets you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

Please examine the output of the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_user_db_resource_governance
```

That will tell you the following information about the current service tier:

- min_cores (cores available on the service)
- max_dop (the MAX_DOP value for the user workload)
- max_sessions (the maximum number of sessions allowed)
- max_db_max_size_in_mb (the maximum max_size value for a data file, in MB)
- log_size_in_mb
- instance_max_worker_threads (worker thread limit for the SQL Server instance)

The above information will give the details of what 10 DTU means in terms of resources available. You can run this query every time you change service tier of the database.